# "Root Element is Missing" on Shared XML when access protected by Mutex

Tags: c#, synchronization, mutex, xmlreader

I have a `settings.xml` document shared between two processes, a Local System service and a WinForms application. Access to the document is controlled by a mutex. Both applications read from and update the xml file at startup.

During testing, if I restart the test machine such that the service automatically starts and the User App starts from the Startup folder, **the service** throws the following exception on about 10% to 20% of test runs:

```
Exception Data:
Exception Type: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: There is an error in XML document (0, 0).
Source: System.Xml
Method: System.Object Deserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader, System.String, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlDeserializationEvents)
Stack Trace: 
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader)
   at lib.ServiceSettings.ReadFromFile() in ServiceSettings.cs:line 107
   at svc.SystemService.settingsFile_Changed(Object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) in Settings.cs:line 152
------------------
InnerException Data:
Exception Type: System.Xml.XmlException
Message: Root element is missing.
Source: System.Xml
Method: Void Throw(System.Exception)
Stack Trace: 
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderServiceSettings.Read4_ServiceSettings()
```

It's a race condition, but I can't duplicate it while debugging. Both applications are using a `static` method from the `ServiceSettings` class to read the settings file:

```
public static ServiceSettings ReadFromFile()
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServiceSettings), ServiceConstants.defaultXmlNamespace);

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(ServiceConstants.defaultFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fileStream))
        {
            return (ServiceSettings)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader); // line 107 exception thrown
        }
    }
}
```

And the call stack points to a `FileSystemWatcher.Changed` event, in which the settings file is read in again - in this case **after the file has been updated by the User App.**

```
private void settingsFile_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    settingsMutex.WaitOne();

    try
    {
        settings = ServiceSettings.ReadFromFile(); // line 152 exception thrown
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        LogExceptionData(ex);
        throw;
    }

    settingsMutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

When I review the xml docucument, the formatting appears to be as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServiceSettings xmlns="svc.settings">
...
</ServiceSettings>
```

I can't see what might be going wrong here. I have a suspicion that it might be related to my use of the `FileStream` object but I can't wrap my head around this one.  Does anyone have any clues for me?  Thanks in advance!

---

Edit

The mutex is created in the same manner for both applications:

```
private static Mutex settingsMutex = null;

private void InitialiseSettings()
{   
    settingsMutex = new Mutex(false, ServiceConstants.mutexName);
    ...
```

Where a `ServiceConstants` class is defined in the **shared library** with a static string for the mutex name:

```
public class ServiceConstants
{
    public const string mutexName = "svc.settings.mutex";
    ...
```

Is this correct for creating a machine-wide mutex?

Comment: 99% you are creating mutex wrong. Please consider to update your post with code showing creation of machine-wide mutex.

Comment: That would make sense... I've added the code above.

Comment: Thanks for this link Alexei, in all my searching I did not come across it. Mind you, until your comment on the mutex, I didn't realise this was the problem.

Comment: Aha! The reason I couldn't reproduce while debugging is the service debugging session was in VS (as a console app) and run under my user session, where the mutex was visible to both applications.

Comment: Please confirm that adding the `"Global\"` prefix to your mutex name solved your problem. If so, this question should be closed as a duplicate of the one proposed by commenter @AlexeiLevenkov.

Comment: It looks to have resolved the issue. I think it can be closed.